# Length of each vector in a list, then add into a vector (R)

Tags: r, list, vector

I have a list like so:

```
s <- list(
     a = c(2, 32, 949), 
     b = c(3, 19, 564, 23), 
     c = c(4, 34)
 )
```

And you can get the length of each vector in the list:

```
length(s[[1]])
[1] 3
length(s[[2]])
[1] 4
length(s[[3]])
[1] 2
```

I want a single vector containing the length of each vector in order, which you can do manually like so:

```
vec <- c(length(s[[1]]),length(s[[2]]),length(s[[3]]))
vec
[1] 3 4 2
```

How do you make a function which takes the list (s) as an argument and returns the vector of lengths (vec)?

Comment: `sapply(s, length)` or more current R version `lengths(s)` btw are you sure your example is right?

Comment: its already done for you in R 3.2+, `lengths(s)`

Comment: Your example seems incorrect, executing `length(s[[2]])` with your `s` variable should return 3.

Comment: See comments above: if you want to use `sapply` and have it as the vector you can do it like this: `as.vector(sapply(s, length))`

Comment: `sapply(s,length)` already returns a named vector. - `is.vector(sapply(s,length))` == TRUE

Comment: @Ricky You're right, it is fixed now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where those numbers, 3, 4, 2, came from. An way to get a vector as they way you want is by applying `sapply` combined with `as.vector`:

```
as.vector(sapply(s, length))
```

Comment: Could you at least thank all the people who commented and already gave this answer?